# Apply with a condition on a Pandas dataframe elementwise

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, conditional-statements, apply

I am learning Python and I try to understand how apply() method works in Pandas dataframes.

As an exercise I would like to use a one line code to apply the str.upper() method on the elements of a Pandas dataframe only if these elements are strings.

I thought to combine a lambda conditional expression with apply but the problem is that when apply calls the Pandas dataframe, the dataframe --if I have understood well -- returns a Series to apply which then passes it to the function.  I wonder how I could get a level deeper and call the function on the elements of the Pandas dataframe.

This is how I do what I intend when apply() calls on a column of the DataFrame (a Series):

```
df= pd.DataFrame([[1, 'a'],['b',2]], columns = ['A', 'B'] )
df['A'].apply(lambda x: str.upper(x) if type(x) is str else x)
```

But how I could do that on the entire dataframe with one line of code?

I am looking for a solution that would work with columns that contain both numerics and strings and would leave the numerics intact.

Comment: you can use `df.applymap()`, but it's EXTREMELY slow - so be careful

Comment: Another thing to note while you're learning: if you're checking if something is a string and converting it to uppercase: `lambda x: x.upper() if isinstance(x, basestring) else x`

Comment: @MaxU : Would you like to post an answer showing how applymap() would be used to solve the specific problem with the examplary dataframe?

Comment: @gk7, there is a good example from piRSquared ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your one-liner

```
df.applymap(lambda x: x.upper() if isinstance(x, str) else x)

   A  B
0  1  A
1  B  2
```

Comment: If this is before Python 3, the OP should use `basestring` and not `str` in `isinstance()`

Comment: @Vincenzzzochi, `basestring` won't work in Python 3, so one would need to use `six`: `import six; df.applymap(lambda x: x.upper() if isinstance(x, six.string_types) else x)` - this should work in both Python 2.x and Python 3.x